# Generated css code not loading

Tags: php, css

I am using php to generate the css files on the fly. But there is a weird outcome. When the page loads, CSS is not applied to any of the elements, though I can view the css code with Chrome developer tools and it looks all correct. And even weirder is that when I edit the code in developer tools panel (like adding a single no-effect white-space), suddenly the css takes effect! I tried clearing cache, no use. Do you have any idea what's wrong?

If it matters:
I am using symfony2.
CSS codes are on a separate file.

Comment: Post some code to show what you're doing. Try to reduce it to the minimum you need to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: How big and how many CSS files are you generating.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest few things: first: have you wrapped the css styles in the `<style></style>` tag pair? If the generated css is in a file, are you linking it correctly like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourpage.php">
```

Adding the charset can help you solving the issue: just add it at the very top of your file.

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

this is useful if your style sheet has not only ASCII chars, so make the browser able to read the file correctly. You can read about this in here: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset.en.php#atcharset and http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#charset

Comment: It is in a separate file. And the link tag looks fine.

Comment: have you tried validating the css? Maybe an inverted comma, a quotation mark or missing semi-colon can break the css

Comment: is the link to the css in the header? Have you tried specifying the `@charset "UTF-8";` at the beginning of your file?

Comment: No, wait sorry. It wasn't the @charset thing that fixed the problem. It was the MIME type I set on the response headers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys. Thank you all. The problem was not the CSS itself. I had not set the content type header to `text/css`, so I think it defaulted to `text/html`. Setting the right header fixed the issue.